# How to parse HH:mm:ss without hours?

Tags: java, parsing, kotlin, time

I have a string with format like: "2h 33m 50s". If hours reach zero this string changes to: "33m 50s". So, if this string goes through LocalTime.parse it throw exception. How can I parse it?

```
fun main() {
    val timeString = "2h 33m 50s"
    val timeString2 = "33m 50s"
    val formatterH = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[H]'h 'm[m]'m 's[s]'s'")
    val formatterM = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("m[m]'m 's[s]'s'")

    val time = LocalTime.parse(timeString, formatterH)
    println(time)
    val time2 = LocalTime.parse(timeString2, formatterH) //throws exception
    println(time2)
    val time3 = LocalTime.parse(timeString2, formatterM) //throws similar exception
    println(time3)
}
```

```
Program output:
02:33:50
Exception in thread "main" org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '33m 50s' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor: DateTimeBuilder[fields={SecondOfMinute=50, NanoOfSecond=0, MicroOfSecond=0, MinuteOfHour=33, MilliOfSecond=0}, ISO, null, null, null], type org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeBuilder
    at org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1559)
    at org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1496)
    at org.threeten.bp.LocalTime.parse(LocalTime.java:437)
    at MainKt.main(main.kt:16)
    at MainKt.main(main.kt)
Caused by: org.threeten.bp.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor: DateTimeBuilder[fields={SecondOfMinute=50, NanoOfSecond=0, MicroOfSecond=0, MinuteOfHour=33, MilliOfSecond=0}, ISO, null, null, null], type org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeBuilder
    at org.threeten.bp.LocalTime.from(LocalTime.java:405)
    at org.threeten.bp.LocalTime$1.queryFrom(LocalTime.java:116)
    at org.threeten.bp.LocalTime$1.queryFrom(LocalTime.java:113)
    at org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeBuilder.build(DateTimeBuilder.java:642)
    at org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1492)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## tl;dr

You are working too hard, and going in the wrong direction.

Regex is overkill for this problem.

No need for [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class, nor a formatting pattern.

Use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class to parse a [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) string crafted from your input.

```
Duration                    // Represent a span-of-time not attached to the timeline with class `Duration`, not `LocalTime`.
.parse(                     // By default, the *java.time* classes such as `Duration` use the standard ISO 8601 formats to parse/generate date-time strings.
    "PT" + "2h 33m 50s"     // Morph your input string to comply with the ISO 8601 standard. Add `P` for the beginning, and `T` to separate years-months-days from hours-minutes-seconds. 
    .replace( " " , "" )    // Delete any SPACE characters by replacing them with nothing.
    .toUpperCase()          // Force all the letters to be uppercase.
)                           // Returns a `Duration`.
```

Ditto for just minutes and seconds.

```
Duration.parse( "PT" + "33m 50s".replace( " " , "" ).toUpperCase() )
```

## `Duration`, not `LocalTime`

> if this string goes through LocalTime.parse

[`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) is for a time-of-day. Your input is not a time-of-day.

Your input string represents a span-of-time unattached to the timeline. The class for that is [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html).

### ISO 8601

Your input string is close to [standard ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format, `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. The `P` marks the beginning. The `T` separates any years-months-days from any hours-minutes-seconds.

Let's adjust your input string to comply with the standard.

```
String input = "PT" + "2h 33m 50s".replace( " " , "" ).toUpperCase() ;
```

> input: PT2H33M50S

Parse.

```
Duration d = Duration.parse( input ) ;  // PT2H33M50S
```

To generate a string in standard ISO 8601, call `toString`.

```
String output = d.toString() ;
```

> output: PT2H33M50S

You can add that `Duration` object to a time-of-day, a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html).

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.NOON.plus( d ) ;
```

You can add that `Duration` to the current moment in UTC to determine a future moment (or a past moment is the duration is a negative amount).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now().plus( d ) ;
```

> lt.toString(): 14:33:50

See all the above [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/UzVOxH).

You can extract each part of the `Duration`.

```
long daysPart = d.toDaysPart() ;  // 24-hour chunks of time, not related to calendar days.
int hoursPart = d.toHoursPart() ;
int minutesPart = d.toMinutesPart() ;
int secondsPart = d.toSecondsPart() ;
```

Or perhaps you want the entire span-of-time as a count of total milliseconds.

```
long millis = d.toMillis() ;  // All the hours-minutes-seconds and such totaled as one count of elapsed milliseconds.
```

Comment: `toUpperCase` is not technically needed, but since durations are conventionally printed in upper case, the principle of least surprise may still require that it be there.

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern `"[H'h ']m'm 's's'"`, which will parse both.

- `[H'h ']` matches the optional hours, e.g. `"2h "`
- `m'm '` matches `"33m "`
- `s's'` matches `"50s"`

Comment: I get `Exception java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '33m 50s' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor: {MicroOfSecond=0, NanoOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=50, MinuteOfHour=33, MilliOfSecond=0},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed`.

Comment: Because `33m 50s` is not a `LocalTime`, it's missing the hour field.

Comment: Correct. So your answer doesn’t work and doesn’t solve the problem asked about.